# Is it feasible to use a Guid as an OAuth2 access token?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I am trying to see if I could get my `OAuth2` provider to return a `Guid` as an access token. I am aware that there are existing and well-defined token providers and formats.

The resulting token would look like this:

```
{
    access_token: "a31b99f9-01d7-7165-09be-73d5b7655f15",
    expires_in: 1799,
    token_type= "bearer"
}
```

I don't need to support claims and the rest of the authentication details will be stored somewhere in the back-end for when I need to validate it (check the expiry, retrieve additional details, etc). I'm just wondering if it's a feasible option as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Tokens maybe passed by "reference" as long as the Authorization Server supports [OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662).

Answer (score 0):

a GUID is not a token. The token includes information which you need to be able to retrieve and work with, otherwise what's the point in having it? The token includes information such as when it expires for example, among other things. If you don't know when the token expires how do you work with it?

You can use a GUID as your ClientID or ClientSecret ( or both ) for example, but that's about as far as you can take it.

Comment: I updated my question to include some more details. Not sure if this  will affect your answer at all but please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Your sample access token meets the requirements set forth by [RFC 6749 Section 1.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.4), so far as I can tell. It explicitly states "the token *may denote an identifier used to retrieve the authorization information* or may self-contain the authorization information in a verifiable manner" (emphasis added). So, database-backed tokens are allowed.